# 3M touchscreen with the android 4.1.2

Tags: android, touchscreen

I have custom android build on the custom omap4 device with the 3M touchscreen. It have been successfully initialised in the system but works as a mouse: there is no touch actions, only slide.

So, as I understand, I need to create idc file for that touchscreen, but I don't know what proper name should be for that file: in the system that thouchscreen have this name: "3M 3M USB Touchscreen - EX II"

Question: What proper name of idc file should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this manual: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/input-device-configuration-files.html idc file can have name like

`/system/usr/idc/Vendor_XXXX_Product_XXXX_Version_XXXX.idc`

So I just search through the sys for the vendor, product and version id. Found them here:

```
/sys/devices/platform/omap/usbhs_omap/ehci-omap.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0/input/input4/id
```

According to that ids my file have such name: Vendor_0596_Product_0001_Version_0410.idc